# What's "walletconflicts" in listtransactions method output

Tags: transactions

Here's an output of listtransactions method

```
[
{
"account" : "",
"address" : "mz2A28GQxWrYgMn2z9pRqaUFNqTMyhk1sJ",
"category" : "receive",
"amount" : 6.30000000,
"confirmations" : 157,
"blockhash" : "00000000befa3ef184f6c3cdec8814b945bad9e3f7ce9eb38e3102bcf4c030c0",
"blockindex" : 9,
"blocktime" : 1397675516,
"txid" : "f517350f088d235878ecab8d5241f0b6e59a4081eec22031c449d0d01d79ed66",
"walletconflicts" : [
],
"time" : 1397672026,
"timereceived" : 1397672026
}
]
```

what's walletconflicts, it's array of what ? transaction ids, maybe ? i couldn't find any documentation even in Bitcoin console.

Answer (score 2):

This is new. It is a field, which contains txids which hold the same data as the original transaction (but has different txids).

See [ID-malleation bug](http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/news/bitcoin-transaction-malleability/2014/02/16)

Comment: Does this indicate a double-spend attack then?

Comment: No, it is not technically a double-spend, but it might indicate some malicious behaviour.

Comment: Can also happen when you bump a fee in a tx. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two or more transactions in your wallet that spend the same output, that field will list the other ones.  That should normally never happen, because bitcoin-qt will refuse to create a transaction that spends an already-spent output.  But if your wallet is corrupt or there's some other problem, it might happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this happens if you bump a fee with some wallets. The old tx will report `"trusted": false`, and both the old and new tx will list the wallet conflicts. The property `walletconflicts` will contain the tx ids of all conflicting transactions (so in a case of one replacement, both the first and the next tx will report the other tx respectively).